# How To View Search Landing Pages In AWStats Or CPanel Log Analyzer

Tags: analytics, cpanel, awstats, logs

I understand that AWStats shows landing pages and search phrases separately. Also, it will show the number of visits from search engines:

[image]

I'm looking for a script or some way to customize the data so that I can see any of the following:

- Landing pages for search referred and their hits
- Landing pages with corresponding search phrase and number of hits

Thus, the output on a custom page or in AWStats would be something like this:

```
Pages referred by search engine:
Page                                          Hits
http://example.com/example-page-1/            25
http://example.com/example-page-2/            36
http://example.com/example-page-3/            10
```

Or

```
Pages referred by search phrases:
Page                                        Phrases               Hits
http://example.com/example-page-1/          search term 1         2
http://example.com/example-page-2/          not provided          14
http://example.com/example-page-3/          search term 3         2
http://example.com/example-page-3/          search term 3.1       3
```

Either of one of these would be extremely helpful. Since the data is collected in logs, I figured there has to be a way to extract it using a script or customization of AWStats.

To be clear, although someone suggested using a third party software, I would still like to write a script to extract this data using Cpanel or AWstats.

Comment: AWStats is very poor. I recommend Piwik. It is free and the very best there is.

Comment: I need to use server logs only - that's why I'm looking for AWstats, Webalizer or any log analyzer. Please upvote if you can.

Comment: Piwik does two things: one, analyze log files; and two, use an **optional** JS bug. Like I said, Piwik is the best there is. If it is possible, then Piwik will do it for free. I pay ***a lot of money(!)*** for a Sawmill license which I will not continue with the intent of using Piwik on the new server.

Comment: Ah! Brilliant. I did not realize Piwik can be used only as a long analyzer. That's great news. I will try it out :-)

Comment: That is what I got out of their web site. I have yet to install it for myself. I have used it to test and compare to other offerings. Let us know how it goes! BTW- I used to be a web host and AWStats was automatically installed. I killed it because there was so much confusion. I used Sawmill and e-mailed daily, weekly, monthly, or custom branded reports however my customer wanted. It was a good but expensive solution. When I shut down the web hosting business, I continued to use Sawmill, but have not updated the license mostly because Piwik is soooooooo good and the price is right. Cheers!!

Comment: You can to what I do. I use older but still decent enough computers to install different OS'es and test different software. I am testing Apache Solr for semantic search and Apache Roller to add blog like features to existing websites without actually having a blog. You made me think that I should install Piwik on the server to figure out how it should be deployed in the future. I am building two new servers and am eyeing a 4 petabyte half rack server pair I cannot afford - yet. ;-) One can always dream - right??

Comment: @closetnoc, thanks but I'm still looking for an AWstats or cpanel script.